# Is there a way to make sure that the first kernel used by Conv2D is the same every time?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am reading about keras as part of an assignment and my supervisor has asked me to see if there is a way initialize Conv2D with the same set of kernels every time. Note: I am not building a model yet, just playing around with the code. Additionally, is there a way to see what kernel it is using (i.e. get the code to print the tensor being used by the filter)?

I have tried to use initializer kernels and setting a value for the random seed:
[screenshot of the code I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSJm.png)

As you can see, the code performs the 2D convolution 100 times and the graph shows the value of the kernel being used (it's 1x1). Why is it not a straight line like this:
[Plot of tf.random.uniform using the same seed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhLdO.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the answer now but I figured I'd keep the post up in case someone else was interested:
[corrected code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtQbP.png)

I think within the kernel generation, keras uses numpy.random so you have to set the seed values for numpy as well.

Comment: Great that you found the answer, but it would be nice to have the code in the answer, not as a link. It is easier to read, copy, and is still there when the image gets deleted on the external site in a few months/years.